# right_join and mutate does not preserve the index in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

I am Mapping `column_data` to `master` and if column value is present in master than it saves it Key
ex:`Parent` for `P` and `Child` for `C`

Problem is i am getting the output but output is indexed differently

**DATA**

```
column_data <- c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "P", "C", "C")
```

```
master  <- list("Parent" = c("P"),
                "Child" = c("C")
               )
```

**CODE**

```
library(dplyr)


df <- data.frame("column" = column_data)
df <-stack(master) %>% 
     type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
     right_join(df, by = c('values' = 'column')) %>%
     mutate(output = coalesce(ind, values))
```

This Should be the output:

```
structure(list(values = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "P", "C", "C"), ind = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Parent", 
"Child", "Child"), output = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "Parent", "Child", "Child")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

but instead i get this as output:

```
structure(list(values = c("P", "C", "C", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), ind = c("Parent", 
"Child", "Child", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), output = c("Parent", "Child", "Child", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: put `data.frame("column" = column_data)` at left?

Comment: where left....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`, if you do a `right_join(x, y)` then the result will include a subset of the matched rows for `x`, then unmatched rows for `y`.

From R documentation on mutating joins, the value returned will be:

> An object of the same type as x. The order of the rows and columns of
> x is preserved as much as possible. The output has the following
> properties:
>
> For inner_join(), a subset of x rows. For left_join(), all x rows. For
> right_join(), a subset of x rows, followed by unmatched y rows. For
> full_join(), all x rows, followed by unmatched y rows.

That is why you have the 3 matched rows at the beginning of your resulting data.frame.

To get the desired result preserving the row order of `df`, try a `left_join` as follows:

```
df2 <- stack(master) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) 

df %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('column' = 'values')) %>%
  mutate(output = coalesce(ind, column))
```

**Output**

```
   column    ind output
1           <NA>       
2           <NA>       
3           <NA>       
4           <NA>       
5           <NA>       
6           <NA>       
7           <NA>       
8           <NA>       
9           <NA>       
10          <NA>       
11          <NA>       
12          <NA>       
13          <NA>       
14          <NA>       
15          <NA>       
16          <NA>       
17      P Parent Parent
18      C  Child  Child
19      C  Child  Child
```